# Creating a bleed margin with a PDF with Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

Is there a way that I can use the `convert` from `imagemagick` command to create a bleed margin in a PDF or even view one?

Comment: For those of us not in the print industry - can you explain or describe in simple, lay terms what you are starting with and what you want to end up with please?

Answer (score 4):

[Bleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_(printing)) is a very common print technique, and ImageMagick offers the concept of "Virtual Pixels" which are the pixels located on the plane outside of "Authentic Pixels".

For example...

Take the following image

```
convert rose: rose.png
```

[image: rose.png]

Set new viewport, and bleed virtual pixel across edge.

```
convert rose.png -set option:distort:viewport 90x66-10-10 \
        -virtual-pixel Edge -filter point \
        -distort SRT 0 +repage output.png
```

[image: output.png]

I bit more creativity (and maths) to include trim lines.

```
convert \( \
   -size 110x86 xc:white -fill none -strokewidth 1 -stroke black \
   -draw "path 'M 20 0 V 85 M 89 0 V 85 M 0 20 H 110 M 0 65 H 110'" \) \
   \( output.png -repage +10+10 \) -layers merge \
   output_with_trim.png
```

[image: output_with_trim]